# DocumentOpen Word event is not working

Tags: c#, events, ms-word

I have this code that open from my C# application a doc file:.

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordApp.Documents.Open(FileName);
wordApp.Visible = true;
wordApp.ActiveWindow.View.FullScreen = true;
var events = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event) wordApp;
events.DocumentOpen += delegate { MessageBox.Show("opended!"); };
events.Quit += delegate { MessageBox.Show("closed!"); };
```

But the document open and I don't get `MessageBox.Show("opended!")` but `MessageBox.Show("closed!")` works fine. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're attaching the `DocumentOpen` event **after** the document has already been opened, so there's no reason for it to be called.

`Quit` works because, well, you haven't **quit** the `WordApplication` yet when it's attached.

Attach both events before you call `DocumentOpen` to open the document.